write a programme in c to skip 2 elements after occurence of a non prime
I write the code as my knowledge but i didnt get the correct ouput.i provide my code below
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i, j, isPrime, n, a[1000], k;

    // Input array limit
    printf("Enter array limit: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    // Input array elements
    printf("Enter array elements:\n");
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    }

    // Loop through the array
    for(i = 0; i < n;  i++;) {
        // Check if current element is prime
        if (a[i] < 2) {
            isPrime = 0; // Numbers less than 2 are not prime
        } else {
            isPrime = 1; // Assume the number is prime
            for (j = 2; j * j <= a[i]; j++) {
                if (a[i] % j == 0) {
                    isPrime = 0; // Found a divisor, not a prime number
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        // Print the current number based on prime status
        if (isPrime) {
            printf("%d ", a[i]);
        } else {
            printf("%d ", a[i]);
            // Skip the next two elements by shifting the array
            for (k = i + 1; k < n - 2; k++) {
                a[k] = a[k + 2];
            }
            n -= 2; // Reduce array size by 2
            i--; // Recheck the current position
        }
      
    }

    return 0;
}

when i run this code i didnt get the correct output.
eg:-
if I enter array limit 9 and print 1-9 i got the output as 1 1 1 1 1 .
Can u please help me to solve this problem
I want a solution for my problem.

This seems like the perfect time to learn how to debug your programs. For example by using a debugger to step through your code line by line while monitoring variables and their values.

Also, please [edit] your question to copy-paste (as text) the full and complete assignment or exercise, including all requirements and limitations. Do you really need to "shift" the array?

A couple of other (unrelated) points: Always check what scanf returns. And if you have an array and user input, check that the user input is valid and within range.

unrelated (small efficiency prime number check tweak): check once for even number, then loop starting at 3 and going by 2 (3, 5, 7, 9, 11, ...)

Find a program that prints primes. There are thousands out there. Compare with your code.

Please note that it is generally expected that you make a debugging attempt yourself before asking for help on Stack Overflow. Questions which do not demonstrate any debugging attempt and do not specify what you have learnt in the debugging attempt, are usually not well received.

Firstly I would like to say that you should probably learn gdb in order to solve simpler things such as this
It seems you also have some small errors within your code:

You have a semicolon in your for loop which you don't need, it should look like the following:
for(i = 0; i < n; i++)

You need to change your logic to actually accept 1 as not being prime
a[i] < 2 to num <= 1

Instead of shifting the array, you should probably index the elements to skip around

Use a while loop instead of a for loop

remove i-- as its leading to the output just being 1


Hopefully this helps a little, but just know that learning to use a debugger and also how to simply google could have probably fixed this issue.
-- Andrew
